# Mysql updating user password

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mybatis

I am trying update password for database using mybatis:

```
update person 
   set name = #{name}, 
       address = #{address}, 
       phoneNumber = #{phoneNumber},
       balance = #{balance}, 
       password = #{password}, 
       id = #{new_id} 
 where id = #{id}
```

However, got following exception:

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null
### The error may involve com.lsp.mybatis.PersonMapper.update-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: update person set name = ?, address = ?, phoneNumber = ?             ,balance = ?, password = ?, id = ? where id = ?
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null
```

I have specified the user id I want to update. Why is it saying "id cannot be null"?

Can someone tell me what I did do wrong?

Comment: Do you want to update `ID` or `password`?

Answer (score 2):

Remove in the query: `id = #{new_id}`.

So, the query will be:

```
update person 
   set name = #{name}, 
       address = #{address}, 
       phoneNumber = #{phoneNumber},
       balance = #{balance}, 
       password = #{password}
 where id = #{id}
```